# ssh-agent running but not working when logged in using PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-agent

When I am using the terminal directly on the machine running Ubuntu 13.04 ssh-add works fine using the process:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

The above process is only started when I log in on the physical machine though.

However, when I login remotely using PuTTY and try ssh-add I instead get:

```
"Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."
```

This is even if I am logged in on the actual machine and thus the ssh-agent process is running as shown above.

To get it working via PuTTY I have to run `exec ssh-agent bash`. But then I have two ssh-agent's running.

Is this normal or is there any way I can change the configuration so the ssh-agent is running automatically no matter if I log in on the machine direct or remote?